# Django somehow tries to render the wrong template

Tags: python, django-2.0

I am working on a project using `Python 3.6` and `Django 2.0.5`. And I have a template named `register_client.html` that I would like to use to render a simple page that will register new clients to the `Client` model.

The following is my complete `urlpatterns`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    re_path(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    re_path(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
    re_path(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    re_path(r'^blog/$', views.blog, name='blog'),
    re_path(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    re_path(r'^lawsuits/$', views.lawsuits_list, name='lawsuits'),
    re_path(r'^my_profile/$', views.my_profile, name='my_profile'),
    re_path(r'^register_client/$', views.register_client, name='register_client'),
    re_path(r'^client/(\d+)/$', views.client, name='client'),
    re_path(r'^client/(\d+)/lawsuits/$', views.lawsuits_list, name='lawsuits'),
    re_path(r'^client/(\d+)/edit/$', views.edit_client, name='edit_client'),
    re_path(r'^client/(\d+)/remove/$', views.remove_client, name='remove_client'),
    re_path(r'^lawsuit/(\d+)/$', views.lawsuit, name='lawsuit'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The pattern that should catch a request to http://localhost/register_client should be `re_path(r'^register_client/$', views.register_client, name='register_client')`.

And here's the view that should render the template appropriately:

```
def register_client(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_staff:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ClientForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                # register a new client
                ...
            else:
                print(form.errors)
        form = ClientForm()
        return render(request, 'register_client.html', {'form': form})
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/') # not_permitted view
```

With the above configurations, Django's giving me a `NoReverseMatch at /register_client/`. And it further states that it is looking up for the view with the name `client`, which is an entirely different view in my `views.py` - `Reverse for 'client' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['client/(\\d+)/$']`

[image: Error Message]

I am running out of ideas and places to look for as to what could be the cause of this. Any help or tip will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a url that goes to `client` on that template?